# Scroll position within a ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a form that with a TabControl that contains a number of TabItems. Each of the TabItems contains a ScrollViewer that contains some various contained content.

My problem - if the size of the form and the TabControl and the contained content is such that the ScrollViewer displays its vertical scrollbars, the content is displayed vertically centered within the ScrollViewer.  In order to see the top of the content, the user needs to manually scroll to the top.

Oddly enough, when the size is such that the Horizontal scrollbars are displayed, the content is initially aligned to the left, which is what I want.

How do I make these ScrollViewers open with the scrollposition initialized to the top?

```
<ParentUserControl>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <Grid>
                        // Assorted Junk
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ChildUserControl />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <OtherChildUserControl />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</ParentUserControl>
```

Comment: Post your current XAML.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed `TabItem` to `ScrollViewer` in your title so that it more accurately reflected your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening is the ScrollIntoView event is being fired. This solution worked for me in the past: [Stop WPF ScrollViewer automatically scrolling to perceived content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384237/stop-wpf-scrollviewer-automatically-scrolling-to-perceived-content)

Comment: I added a handler for RequestBringIntoView to each of the ScrollViewer, and in it set e.Handled = true. The event is firing, and the handler is executing, but the behavior is unchanged.

Comment: You might need to add the RequestBringIntoReview handler to the control that's being shown. Try putting it on either the ChildUserControl, the OtherChildUserControl, the TabItem, or the TabControl.  For me I was changing the visibility of a StackPanel that was causing the scrollviewer to auto-scroll

Comment: Putting the RequestBringIntoView handler on the contents of the ScrollViewers, instead of on the ScrollViewers, solved the problem. Thanks.